# See if a folder is open in Windows explorer

Tags: java, windows, windows-explorer

So here I have a problem. I want to see if a certain file is open in Windows Explorer so that when I press a button, it goes to the corresponding directory. Is there a way to do that?

My code is like this:

```
JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Go To PE");
    btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(/*folder is open in explorer*/) {
                //open other folder
            }
        }
    });
```

I know how to open the designated file, i just need to check if certain folder is currently open. Any ideas?

Comment: `Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);` if the file specified by `f` is open in an explorer, then (at least windows) shows it in the open window. No need to check there. Otherwise it should be enough to check if you can write to that file

Comment: OK. Thanks for the help! I may need to clarify, though. Is there a way to see if one is open? I need to open a second, completely independent one based on whether or not the first is open.